# $ T: R^{n} \rightarrow R^{m} $ is a linear transformation $ \Rightarrow $ $ T $ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Suppose that the spaces $ R^{n} $ and $ R^{m} $ have their usual topology. Let $ T: R^{n} \rightarrow R^{m} $ be a linear transformation, show that $ T $ is continuous.

If $ T: R^{n} \rightarrow R^{m} $ is a linear transformation, then there exists a positive constant $M$ such that $ \Vert T(x)\Vert \leq M \Vert x \Vert $ for all $ x $ in $ R^{n} $ . This implies that $ T $ is continuous:

if $ x_{0} \in R^{n} $ y $ \epsilon >0 $ are arbitrary, then
$ T(B(x_{0}, \dfrac{\epsilon}{M})) \subseteq B(T(x_{0}), \epsilon)$.

Could you explain why the last row shows that $T$ is continuous?

Comment: The last rowshows  that inverse image of any open set is open

Comment: @AbishankaSaha Actually, the last row is more along the lines of showing that the preimage of a ball centered in $T(x_0)$ is a neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yeah exactly. I meant only that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last row may be interpreted topologically as an attempt to show that, for all $x_0$, the preimage of a neighbourhood of $T(x_0)$ is a neighbourhood of $x_0$. For that purpose, proving that the preimage of any open ball centered in $T(x_0)$ contains an open ball centered in $x_0$ is sufficient. This can be recovered by applying these two basic facts of set theory to the containment $T(B(x_0,\epsilon/M))\subseteq B(T(x_0),\epsilon)$:

- if $f:X\to Y$ and $A\subseteq B\subseteq Y$, then $f^{-1}(A)\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$
- if $f:X\to Y$, and $C\subseteq X$, then $f^{-1}(f(C))\supseteq C$.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to for every $\epsilon>0$, for all $|x-x_{0}|<\epsilon/M$, then $T(x)\in B(T(x_{0},\epsilon)$, so $|T(x)-T(x_{0})|<\epsilon$, this is the closed form to the classical continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)$ s.t. $\|x-y\|\le\delta$ hold. Then $\|Tx-Ty\|\le M\|x-y\|<M\delta$. Choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{M}$. This shows that $T$ is in fact, uniformly continuous.